# In Microsoft Dynamics CRM, Is it possible to create entities in different database schemas?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I've started to use Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015. By default it creates the entities in `dbo`.

**Question:** Is it possible to create entities in custom database schema? (per solution, per case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The idea of Dynamics CRM is that the organization of the database is basically a black box. The only supported modifications to the database are the addition of custom indexes.